# I want the 10 week weight to be higher than the 6 week weight, and the 40 week weight to be higher than the 10 week weight, etc

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, conditional-statements, mutate

According to my follow-up data, I want the 10 week weight to be higher than the 6 week weight, and the 14 week weight to be higher than the 10 week weight, etc.

[here you can see data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JwCS.png)

I am trying this code:

```
wght_data %>% mutate(
  wght_correct = ifelse(
    wght1_ia6w <= wght1_ia10w &
      wght1_ia10w <= wght1_ia14w &
      wght1_ia14w <= wght1_ia6m &
      wght1_ia6m <= wght1_ia9m &
      wght1_ia9m <= wght1_ia12m &
      wght1_ia12m <= wght1_ia18m &
      wght1_ia18m <= wght1_ia24m, 1, 0)) -> wght_data
```

Comment: Hi Ashu! Welcome to StackOverflow. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: use `dput` on `wght_data`, and then add the output of that to your question

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly, the issue is with the data:

```
> wght_data
  wght1_ia6w wght1_ia10w wght1_ia14w wght1_ia6m wght1_ia9m wght1_ia12m
1       3910        5276        5630       7416       8138        8762
  wght1_ia18m wght1_ia24m
1        9330          NA
```

The last part of your condition is `wght1_ia18m <= wght1_ia24m`, which in the case of this row (and every other row in your screenshot) is that `wght1_ia24m` is NA, not a number, so it evaluates to `NA`, and so the whole condition evaluates to `NA`.

If you want to fix this, there's a few things you can do:

1. Remove that last part of the condition
2. Add a check for NAs (it's up to you to decide if wght1_ia18m <= wght1_ia24m should evaluate to true or false when wght1_ia24m is NA)
3. Replace NAs with something else (e.g. 0)

I hope this helps!

Comment: also, I see there are NAs in the second last column. It might be best to use the second or third solutions, rather than the first